# Chromebook app compatibility

Tags: android, chromebook

I am working on android app, that has to be runnable on chromebooks.

Application works fine, but I can't seem to make it's manifest compatible with chromebooks. I need to do this, so that application can be distributed by google play. I updated my my manifest several times , but still nothing. Here is `aapt` dump:

```
feature-group: label=''
  uses-gl-es: '0x20000'
  uses-feature-not-required: name='android.hardware.camera'
  uses-feature-not-required: name='android.hardware.camera.autofocus'
  uses-feature: name='android.hardware.location'
  uses-feature-not-required: name='android.hardware.location.GPS'
  uses-feature: name='android.hardware.location.gps'
  uses-feature-not-required: name='android.hardware.sensor.accelerometer'
  uses-feature-not-required: name='android.hardware.telephony'
  uses-feature-not-required: name='android.hardware.touchscreen'
  uses-feature: name='android.hardware.wifi'
  uses-feature: name='android.hardware.screen.portrait'
  uses-implied-feature: name='android.hardware.screen.portrait' reason='one or more activities have specified a portrait orientation'
main
other-activities
other-services
supports-screens: 'small' 'normal' 'large' 'xlarge'
supports-any-density: 'true'
```

I disabled camera permissions, GPS permissions, and I can't get google play to show my application on my chromebook.

Is there anything I forgot to add to the manifest ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Most chromebooks are x86 based....are you supporting that? (typically configured using `splits` section in build.gradle)....for example, something like:

```
  splits {

    abi {
      enable true
      reset()
      include "x86", "armeabi-v7a"
      universalApk false
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

After little bit of experimenting I found out that to disable hw.location.gps I had to create this manifest

```
<!-- manifest is merged, remove previous occurence of ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" tools:node="remove" />

<!-- I have no idea why I need to have duplicates here, but without them, hw.location.gps is added to requirements -->
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"  android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature  android:name="android.hardware.screen.portrait" android:required="false"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" android:required="false"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front" android:required="false"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash" android:required="false"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth" android:required="false"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.microphone" android:required="false"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location" android:required="false"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.network" android:required="false"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" android:required="false"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false"/>
```

I am removing ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission from one of my libraries.
Also If I remove one of the duplicates location.gps it does not work. I don't know why, but this manifest works.